# Graphics not drawing in paintComponent(Graphics)?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm working on a custom Swing Component for my application, and I started drawing things with the `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Everything works fine except for the fact that I can't draw any rectangles. I think the problem is with the `getX()` and `getY()` part, but I don't know that for sure. Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (mouseEntered) {
        g.setColor(HIGHLIGHTED_COLOR);
    } else {
        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    }

    g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());


    //Draw rest of stuff (works fine)
```

The API says that it is supposed to be used like this: `g.fillRect(x, y, width, height)`, and that's what I'm doing.

The rest of the drawing works perfectly, but I can't figure out why this isn't drawing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how your *Component* is defined, but the default value for a *Component*'s `getX()` method is the X coordinate of the *Component*'s upper left hand corner (relative to the root Component).

When you are drawing in a *Component*'s `paintComponent(Graphics)` method in Swing, the origin of the *Graphics* context that you are drawing to is typically located at the top-left of the ***Component*** itself, not the root *Component*.

So by doing this call:

```
g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
```

You are likely drawing the rectangle outside of the clip bounds of the *Component*!

(e.g. if the Component is located at 100, 100 and it has a width of 20 and height of 20, the rectangle you are drawing, in **absolute** coordinates, is at `(200, 200)` to `(220, 220)`)

If you want to draw a rectangle that encompasses the entire component, you may want to try something more like this:

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

This will draw from the origin (again, likely the top-left hand corner of the Component) down to the width and height of the component.

(Using previous example: Component is at 100, 100, and width/height of 20, the rectangle this would draw is at `(100, 100)` to `(120, 120)`)

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Oooh! That makes so much sense! Thanks a lot!